# Why is this Tkinter script saying tk is not defined?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just starting out in trying to build a GUI using Tkinter and I can't for the life of me figure out why this script isn't working. I am using Python 3 on my RHEL 7 machine but it keeps spitting out errors.

```
from tkinter import * tk
import tkinter as tk

fields = 'IP (Ex:224.8.8.7)', 'PORT (Ex:8208)'


def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))


def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = []
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
        entries.append((field, ent))
    return entries


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1 = tk.Button(root, bg="green", fg="white", text='start',
                   command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1.pack(anchor="nw", padx=5, pady=5)

    b2 = tk.Button(root, bg="red", fg="white", text="stop")
    b2.pack(anchor="sw", padx=5, pady=5)

    b3 = tk.Button(root, bg="black", fg="white", text='exit', command=root.quit)
    b3.pack(side="bottom", anchor="se", padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `from tkinter import * tk` isn't valid syntax.  Use `from tkinter import *`

Comment: change the first line to `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: I would suggest _not_ using `from tkinter import *` since you've got the other one — because `import *` is considered a poor programming practice since it pollutes the namespace, invites confusing errors, and makes them harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is all about syntax you have used.

The statement:

```
from tkinter import * tk
```

**Here:**

1. This command would try to import modules from tkinter package.
2. This command will try to import `*` and `tk` as the syntax has this work.

**Error:**

You can see an error as the `tkinter` package has no module named `tk`. Therefore this error pops up. You have already imported the module as `tk` in 2nd statement:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Thus you shouldn't use `tk` in first statement.

**Conclusion & Solution:**
Remove the `tk` in the first statement and then run the program. It would surely work then

---

Hope this helps. If you still get any error, feel free to comment and ask me.

Thank you! :)